# ModifyAppliesToRange not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with many duplicated Conditional Formatting instances.
I'm trying to write code to tidy/delete many of them.

I need to modify the Format Condition.
Any idea why the following doesn't work?

```
Sub UpdateCondition(ByRef bFirst As Boolean, rng As Range, f As FormatCondition, replacementFormula As String)

    If bFirst Then
        f.Modify f.Type, , replacementFormula
        f.ModifyAppliesToRange rng
        bFirst = False
    Else
        f.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

I get the following error:

> Method 'ModifyAppliesToRange' of object 'FormatCondition' failed

This code works for many of my conditions. Only some of them trip up.

-- edit --

My calling code is as follows

```
Dim f As FormatCondition
Dim bFirst As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

Set rng = SomeRangeOnTheSheet

bFirst = True
For i = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells.Address).FormatConditions.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set f = ws.Range(Cells.Address).FormatConditions(i)
    If f.Formula1 = "..Some Formula.." Then
        UpdateCondition bFirst, rng, f, replacementFormula
    End If
Next
```

-- edit --

```
Function SomeRangeOnTheSheet() As Range
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim cell2 As Range

    Set cell1 = Cells(Range("Roster").row, Range("StartDate").Column)
    Set cell2 = Cells(Range("Roster").row + Range("Roster").Rows.Count - 1, Range("Roster").Column + Range("Roster").Columns.Count - 1)
    Set RosterDataRange = Range(cell1, cell2)

End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: Need to see what is passed to this function in order to debug it.

Comment: How do you actually set `rng` in the calling code?  What's `f` declared as?

Comment: f should be declared as Object or Variant, because not all conditional formattings are of type `FormatCondition`. If I remember correctly only the ones that have a formula are of type `FormatCondition`. Also,  `Cells.FormatConditions` instead of `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells.Address).FormatConditions`

Comment: Thanks Slai. That's not my problem however. All the conditional formattings on my sheet are of type FormatCondition. My error occurs when I run the ModifyAppliesToRange statement.